# Powerquery: Replace 1 double quote(") with 2 double quotes("")

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want to create a JSON from CSV file in PowerBI in the following format:

> "{""data"": [{""AGE"": ""5"", ""SEX"": ""2"", ""BMI"": ""3.1"",""BP"":
> ""3.1"", ""S1"": ""3.1"", ""S2"": ""3.1"", ""S3"": ""3.1"",""S4"":
> ""3.1"",""S5"": ""3.1"", ""S6"": ""3.1""}, {""AGE"": ""51"", ""SEX"":
> ""2"", ""BMI"": ""3.1"",""BP"": ""3.1"", ""S1"": ""3.1"", ""S2"":
> ""3.1"", ""S3"": ""3.1"",""S4"": ""3.1"",""S5"": ""3.1"", ""S6"":
> ""3.1""}]}"

I am able to reach a point(Using Json.FromValue and Text.FromBinary) as shown below:
{"data":

> {"data":[{"AGE":59,"SEX":1,"BMI":43,"BP":70,"S1":157,"S2":93.2,"S3":38,"S4":4,"S5":4.8598,"S6":87,"Y":151},{"AGE":48,"SEX":1,"BMI":21.6,"BP":87,"S1":183,"S2":103.2,"S3":70,"S4":3,"S5":3.8918,"S6":69,"Y":75}]}"

But still not able to get the double quotes around the field names.

Can anybody provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to specify the double-quote character `"` inside a string, you have to use a double double-quote `""` so that it's clear you aren't intending to end the string context. This means that to get a double double-quote, you need to use a quadruple double-quote `""""`.

**Edit:** Try the Transform > Replace Values feature:

[image: Replace Values box]

Comment: When I am trying to give a single " in a string and want to replace it with a double ", I give the below command: Text.Replace(concat,""","""").. But getting syntax error..

Comment: Like I explained, you need to use `""` to represent `"` when you are inside quotes. Try `Text.Replace(concat,"""","""""")` instead.

Comment: Getting the error: Expression.Error: 2 arguments were passed to a function which expects 3.

Comment: You'll get that error if you have an odd number of `"` in the last two arguments. Make sure you have 4 and 6.